# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „vorliegen“, „geben“ und „bestehen“ im Sinne von „existieren“?

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *vorliegen*, *geben* und *bestehen*?

> Es liegt ein Problem vor.
>   Es gibt ein Problem.
>   Es besteht ein Problem.

Comment: Ich hab daraus mal einen vollständigen Satz gemacht, dann ist es etwas weniger abstrakt. Falls dir das nicht zusagt, kannst du die Änderung gerne rückgängig machen.

Comment: Wenn _es_ ein Problem _gibt_ und dieses Problem vielleicht sogar länger _besteht_, dann wird es wohl irgendwann jemandem _vorliegen_, der sich damit auseinander setzen darf.

Comment: Um auch noch die Syntax anzusprechen: Bei "vorliegen" und "bestehen" steht "ein Problem" im Nominativ; das "es" ist hier nur Platzhalter, damit das Verb an der zweiten Position stehen kann. Bei "geben" steht "ein Problem" im Akkusativ; auf das "es" kann auch durch Umstellen nicht verzichtet werden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beginnen wir mit dem Kniffligsten:

**Vorliegen**

Es hebt sich von den anderen deutlich ab, indem es eine Person voraussetzt, die das Vorliegende wahrnimmt. Und dies in der Regel aktiv und nicht bloß am Rande. Diesen Bezug auf einen Rezipienten zeigen auch alle Definitionen im Duden klar.

> 1. vorgelegt sein; sich (als Material zur Begutachtung) in jemandes Händen befinden
> 2. als Faktum für eine entsprechende Beurteilung zu erkennen sein; als zu berücksichtigende Tatsache für etwas bestehen

**Existieren**

Ist schwer zu definieren, aber leicht zu benutzen. Es beschreibt, dass etwas real... ist.

> Es existieren Hinweise, aber sie liegen uns nicht vor.

Es kann auch "überleben" bedeuten.

> Aufgrund des Wassermangels können Menschen hier kaum existieren.

**Geben**

Meines Erachtens umgangssprachliches inhaltliches Äquivalent zu existieren, aber strikt auf dessen erste Bedeutung beschränkt. Es gibt aber Verwendungspräferenzen, die ich noch nicht festnageln konnte.

**Bestehen**

kann schlicht "existieren" bedeuten, es kann aber auch den Fortbestand betonen, wobei ein äußerer Widersacher oder zerrüttender Einfluss meist präsenter ist als bei der ähnlichen Bedeutung von "existieren".

> Die Bauwerke bestehen schon seit Menschengedenken.

Diese Bedeutung von "bestehen" ist es, die wohl am ehesten mit "Problemen" verknüpft wird. Der Fokus liegt dann häufig darauf, dass die Probleme nicht gelöst wurden.

> Besteht das Problem noch?

Eng verwandt mit solchem Fortbestand ist eine Form des sich Bewährens:

> Gegen diesen Gegner kann ich sicher bestehen!

Drittens kann es das "konstituiert sein" bedeuten.

> Dieser Rock besteht aus Leinen.

Ich vermute, dies ist seine elementarste Bedeutung, welche die anderen bedingte. Was in seine Bestandteile zerfiel, das besteht nicht mehr.

Es gibt noch die Bedeutung des Beharrens, und sicher verwundert es nicht, dass zwischen Beharrlichkeit und Beständigkeit eine Brücke geschlagen wurde.

> Ich bestehe auf einem Kuss als Zeichen Ihrer Dankbarkeit!

Comment: @Loong Danke für Ihre Edits!

Comment: Ludi, vielleicht ist es dir nur entgangen, aber üblicherweise duzen wir uns hier: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/36/umgangsformen-du-oder-sie